# writing APIC to mp3 file with getid3 (id3v2)

Tags: php, id3-tag, apic, getid3

I am trying to write APIC picture to mp3 file with getid3. here is the code;

```
$cover = "/home/user/public_html/artwork/cover.jpg";
$TagData['attached_picture'][]=array(
'picturetypeid'=>2, // Cover. More: module.tag.id3v2.php -> function APICPictureTypeLookup
'description'=>'cover', // text field
'mime'=>'image/jpeg', // Mime type image
'data'=>$cover // Image data
);
```

but it doesnt work. image size is around 1.5 MB. should i resize it or sth ?

where am i wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What library are you using, and how are you saving the data into the MP3 file?

Comment: i use getid3 library http://www.getid3.org/

Comment: i can save title,artist,album etc info without any problem but when it comes to APIC it doesnt work properly

Comment: we need more code, up to the WriteID3v2 call.

Comment: also: does it throw an error or does it just fail silently?

Comment: hi, it doesnt fail actually, i just cant just see the image in id3 tags and as a file icon.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the demo they have on their website: http://www.getid3.org/source/demo.write.phps

snippet of code:

```
$fd = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb')
$APICdata = fread($fd, filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
fclose ($fd);

$imagetypes = array(1=>'gif', 2=>'jpeg', 3=>'png');
if (isset($imagetypes[$APIC_imageTypeID])) {
    $TagData['attached_picture'][0]['data']          = $APICdata;
    $TagData['attached_picture'][0]['picturetypeid'] = $_POST['APICpictureType'];
    $TagData['attached_picture'][0]['description']   = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $TagData['attached_picture'][0]['mime']          = 'image/'.$imagetypes[$APIC_imageTypeID];
}
```

Seems like the data key needs to be the image content, not just the path to the image file.
So in your case, it should be something like:

```
$cover = "/home/user/public_html/artwork/cover.jpg";
$fd = fopen($cover, 'rb')
$APICdata = fread($fd, filesize($coverFile));
fclose ($fd);

$TagData['attached_picture'][]=array(
'picturetypeid'=>2, // Cover. More: module.tag.id3v2.php -> function APICPictureTypeLookup
'description'=>'cover', // text field
'mime'=>'image/jpeg', // Mime type image
'data'=>$APICdata  // Image data
);
```

Note: This is just after a quick glance at the demo code, I have not used this library or tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

GetID3 needs the content of the file to be send for the data, not the file path. Then only it will be able to embed them into the file. Try

```
$cover = "/home/user/public_html/artwork/cover.jpg";
$TagData['attached_picture'][]=array(
    'picturetypeid'=>2, // Cover. More: module.tag.id3v2.php -> function APICPictureTypeLookup
    'description'=>'cover', // text field
    'mime'=>'image/jpeg', // Mime type image
    'data'=> file_get_contents($cover) // Image data; not the file name
);
```

tested and working :)

Comment: doesnt work for a reason :( i put these lines after that $tagwriter->tag_data = $TagData;
$tagwriter->WriteTags();

Comment: And what error you are getting? or its just it wont get inserted into the file?

Comment: if its causing the problem then it might be the size of the file, try resizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the source code:

```
case 'APIC':
    // 4.14  APIC Attached picture
    // Text encoding      $xx
    // MIME type          <text string> $00
    // Picture type       $xx
    // Description        <text string according to encoding> $00 (00)
    // Picture data       <binary data>
```

So picture data must be binary.

The solution is here: [getid3 demo](http://phpxref.com/xref/getid3/demos/demo.write.php.source.html)

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me for long time:

```
    $TagData = array(); //your other tags
    $fd = fopen($albumPath, 'rb');
    $APICdata = fread($fd, filesize($albumPath));
    fclose($fd);

    if($APICdata) {
        $TagData += array(
            'attached_picture' => array(0 => array(
                'data'          => $APICdata,
                'picturetypeid' => '0x03',
                'description'   => 'cover',
                'mime'          => image_type_to_mime_type($albumExifType)
            ))
        );
    }
    //and write the tags to file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// getID3() by James Heinrich <info@getid3.org>               //
//  available at http://getid3.sourceforge.net                 //
//            or http://www.getid3.org                         //
//          also https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3       //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                             //
// /demo/demo.simple.write.php - part of getID3()              //
// Sample script showing basic syntax for writing tags         //
// See readme.txt for more details                             //
//                                                            ///
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//die('Due to a security issue, this demo has been disabled. It can be enabled by removing line '.__LINE__.' in '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$TextEncoding = 'UTF-8';
$albumPath = "img/img.jpg"; // path to your image


require_once('../getid3/getid3.php');
// Initialize getID3 engine
$getID3 = new getID3;
$getID3->setOption(array('encoding'=>$TextEncoding));

require_once('../getid3/write.php');
// Initialize getID3 tag-writing module
$tagwriter = new getid3_writetags;
//$tagwriter->filename = '/path/to/file.mp3';
$tagwriter->filename = 'uploads/problem.mp3';

//$tagwriter->tagformats = array('id3v1', 'id3v2.3');
$tagwriter->tagformats = array('id3v2.3');

// set various options (optional)
$tagwriter->overwrite_tags    = true;  // if true will erase existing tag data and write only passed data; if false will merge passed data with existing tag data (experimental)
$tagwriter->remove_other_tags = false; // if true removes other tag formats (e.g. ID3v1, ID3v2, APE, Lyrics3, etc) that may be present in the file and only write the specified tag format(s). If false leaves any unspecified tag formats as-is.
$tagwriter->tag_encoding      = $TextEncoding;
$tagwriter->remove_other_tags = true;

// populate data array
$TagData = array(
    'title'         => array('My Song'),
    'artist'        => array('My Song'),
    'album'         => array('My Song'),
    'year'          => array('20015'),
    'genre'         => array('My Song'),
    'comment'       => array('My Song'),
    'track'         => array('01'),
);

$fd = fopen($albumPath, 'rb');
$APICdata = fread($fd, filesize($albumPath));
fclose($fd);

if($APICdata) {
    $TagData += array(
        'attached_picture' => array(0 => array(
            'data'          => $APICdata,
            'picturetypeid' => '0x03',
            'description'   => 'cover',
            'mime'          => image_type_to_mime_type(@$albumExifType)
        ))
    );
}



$tagwriter->tag_data = $TagData;

// write tags
if ($tagwriter->WriteTags()) {
    echo 'Successfully wrote tags<br>';
    if (!empty($tagwriter->warnings)) {
        echo 'There were some warnings:<br>'.implode('<br><br>', $tagwriter->warnings);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Failed to write tags!<br>'.implode('<br><br>', $tagwriter->errors);
}
```

For anyone who just needd to update their ID3 tags including the Album Art , above code works just fine  You need to have getID3 library to work .
This Answer is based on JacopKane's Answer so credit goes to him